# How does a compiler choose which function to link?

Tags: c, linker

I have a program (`main.c`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int result = sqrt(9);
    printf("result: %d\n" ,result);
    return 0;
}

double sqrt(double blah) {
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, my result is

```
result: 3
```

This would tell me the linker is choosing the `libm` library's `sqrt` function instead of mine to call in my `main` function.

I don't get any errors or warnings when I compile this program with all warnings enabled:

```
gcc main.c -Wall
```

My questions:

- Why did the linker not choose my definition of `sqrt` to call?

  - is this deterministic?
- Why did I not get any errors or warnings? It seems that multiple definitions of a function with the same signature is a gotcha that should be indicated somehow.
- Is there a way to output what functions were linked to where? So if I come across a case where the unexpected definition is referenced, I can debug?

The only thing I can think of is when I run `gcc --precompile`, I see this function declaration:

```
extern double sqrt(double);
```

Does this tell the linker that sqrt is defined outside of this file?  And since this already satisfies the definition of `sqrt`, my own definition is ignored when linking?

gcc info (I know it is really clang, since I am on mac, not sure if that makes a difference in terms of this question)

```
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Edit:

The assembly output:

```s
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 10, 15    sdk_version 10, 15
    .section    __TEXT,__literal8,8byte_literals
    .p2align    3               ## -- Begin function main
LCPI0_0:
    .quad   4621256167635550208     ## double 9
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movsd   LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0    ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    sqrtsd  %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvttsd2si   %xmm0, %eax
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %esi
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    movl    %esi, %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function
    .globl  _sqrt                   ## -- Begin function sqrt
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_sqrt:                                  ## @sqrt
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movsd   %xmm0, -8(%rbp)
    xorps   %xmm0, %xmm0
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function
    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz  "result: %d\n"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if it's replacing the function call with a constant value calculated at compile time. Check the assembly output.

Comment: I am not an expert in the assembly family that this compiles to, but it does look as if sqrt is defined in the .s assembly file.  I can see what I think is the definition and what I think is the call.

Comment: @Shawn I added the assembly output to the original question

Comment: `sqrtsd  %xmm0, %xmm0`. That's not a function call. So it appears that the compiler has converted it to direct assembly instructions (which makes sense).

Comment: thank you both for your help.  This indirectly answers most of my questions.  I see now that a function call would be something like "callq _printf".  In the future, I will check the assembly output when I am unsure what function is being linked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names of standard C library function are reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage. You are not supposed to use them for your own functions. This means that when you use a reserved name, the compiler may assume it is the standard function, not your own implementation. Then, to optimize your program (even without full optimization turned on), the compiler may replace a call to `sqrt` with the processor’s square root instruction. Or the compiler could even calculate the result itself and build that into the assembly code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  You say that the compiler "may" assume it is the standard function and "may" replace the call with the instruction.  Does this mean this is not always the case? And I should always check the assembly output if I am unsure?

Comment: @northsideknight: Whether the compiler decides to replace a call to `sqrt` with a processor instruction or calculate it itself may depend on various factors: Which compiler it is, whether optimization is enabled, whether the compiler can deduce the exact value of the argument, whether the compiler can see the program does not depend on any features that are in `sqrt` that are not in the instruction, such as setting the `errno` variable, and so on. Rather than checking the assembly, you should simply never use `sqrt` for your own function name.

Comment: I am marking this answer correct.  I think what is important here is: check the generated assembly to see what exactly the compiler collection is doing with the code in question.  And I agree, I would never name a function `sqrt` (or anything that would conflict with an included library), this question was more for an explanation as to what was happening and how to debug.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem you have not acquainted for:

When you linked your executable, you specified `-lm` in order to provide both versions of the `sqrt()` function, the one you provided, and the `libm.so` shared executable.

The problem is that the shared executable probably will take preference because linking is done at load time, your function is an instrinsic function, and the compiler has not resolved the reference before closing the compiled `.o`.  This makes the dynamic linker to select one of the functions at shared object loading time.

When there were no shared binaries, the `sqrt()` function was indeed in a `sqrt.o` file that was stored in `libm.a`, and the linker selected only the binaries from the archive that were resolving some unresolved references, in that case, the `sqrt.o` from `libm.a` should have not been included, and your `sqrt()` should have been referenced instead.

By the way, there's also an issue in how the compiler treats the `sqrt()` function since the compiler accepts to support what is called an intrinsic function (as `sqrt()` is)  They normally take preference and so, you are somehow advised not to name your functions like the intrinsic ones.  This aspect, which is very extended in FORTRAN, has not been an issue until now.  The compiler treats completely different the intrinsic functions from others... and you will see that with other library functions doesn't happen.

You will see this thing to emerge as a warning from the compiler if you try to define `sqrt()` as a different function (for example, an `unsigned sqrt(unsigned n);` integer version of the square root)  The compiler will emit a warning suggesting you to rename your function so you don't use the same name of an instrinsic function.  I have not digged this deeply, but somehow, the compiler knows the existence of some functions before any definition is `#include`d.